# NVX RestAPI does not return CREST-XSRF-TOKEN in request via Postman

Tags: rest, postman

Following the authentication steps using Postman in https://sdkcon78221.crestron.com/sdk/DM_NVX_REST_API/Content/Topics/Authentication.htm, I can do the first GET to get the TRACKID and other cookies, but then when I do the second step, the POST to userlogin with the TRACKID, Origin and Referer set, I get a 200 back from the NVX, but I do NOT get  CREST-XSRF-TOKEN in the header.
Following this, calls to get deviceID info fail and I'm stuck here on this fairly basic step.
The docs mention authentication but don't mention how to set this in Postman?
Is the documentation out of date? Is that why the CREST-XSRF-TOKEN is no longer sent?
Can this all still be done via Postman, the other thread implied it needed to be done via NodeJS which seems odd for a RestAPI.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I had an email with Crestron and said the CREST-XSRF-TOKEN will not be generated or exist when your NVX units are not set to SSL (Crestron Default). They said the manuals are lacking this info for non-sll API control and they will put rewriting the manual on their to-do-list. Knowing Crestron this will never ever happen. I'm still doing trial and error as we speak.